# Comparison between variables pointing to same Integer object

Tags: java, integer

The output of current program is "Strange". But both the variables share the same reference. Why are the second and third comparisons not true?

```
Integer a;
Integer b;
a = new Integer(2);
b = a;
if(b == a) {
    System.out.println("Strange");
}
a++;
if(b == a) {
    System.out.println("Stranger");
}
a--;
if(b == a) {
    System.out.println("Strangest");
}
```

Output: `Strange`

Comment: Unboxing is probably the answer.  However, I have no real idea.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating an unforgivable use of autoboxing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's the artifact of autoboxing and a fact that Integer is immutable in Java.

The `a++` and `a--` are translated to roughly this.

```
int intA = a.getInt( );
intA++;
a = Integer.valueOf( intA ); // this is a reference different from b
```

Comment: Note that if you replace `a = new Integer(2)` with `a = Integer.valueOf(2)`, "Strangest" will also be printed since it will use the integer cache for getting the instance.

Comment: What do you mean by integer cache in your comment. can you elaborate ?

Comment: @restrictedinfinity. At least in Sun's Java, Byte, Short and Integer have a cache of 256 values ranging from -128 to 127 inclusive that are served by `Type.valueOf( )` method.  So in our case after `a--` the int value is `2` and that would be the same that we have started with, so `Integer.valueOf( 2 )` would have returned the same `Integer` object.  Note, that `Long` type does not have a cache, therefore `Long.valueOf` always returns a new object.

Comment: @Alexander: It can be safely assumed that this behaviour holds true for all JVM implementations since it is a part of the specification.

Comment: @Sanjay it is part of the specification, but it only guarantees to cache -128 to +127. However, implementations may cache more than this if they choose. This means if it chooses to cache more, an `==` comparison of, say `valueOf(200)` may prove to be `true` on some implementations but `false` on others.

Comment: @glowcoder: I was actually correcting the statement "At least in Sun's Java, Byte, Short and Integer have a cache of 256 values ranging from -128 to 127 inclusive that are served by Type.valueOf( ) method" since he didn't really need to mention "Sun" Java; this behaviour is consistent across all implementations since it's a part of the specification. Of course, as you correctly observed, nothing definitive can be said about values which don't fall in the range decided by the specification.

Answer (score 8):

- `Strage` - it's obvious, the two variables point to the same object
- not `Stranger` because of autoboxing. `Integer` is immutable, so each operation on it creates a new instance.
- not `Strangest`, because of the previous point, and because you have used `new Integer(..)` which ignores the cache that is used for the byte range. If you use `Integer.valueOf(2)` initially, then the cached `Integer`s will be used and `Strangest` will also be printed.

Answer (score 0):

An Integer object is immutable, any change in an existing object will create a new object. So after `a++`, a new object will be created and `a` will start pointing to that new object while `b` is still pointing to the old object. Hence, after `a++`, `a` and `b` are pointing to different objects and `a == b` will always return false.

with respect to the mentioned example :

```
Integer a; //created Integer reference   
Integer b;  //created Integer reference  
a = new Integer(2);//created new Integer Object and a reference is assigned to that new object   
b = a;//b also start pointing to same Integer object   
if(b == a) { // b==a will be true as both are pointing to same object   
System.out.println("Strange");   
}
a++; //after a++ , a new Integer object will be created (due to Integer immutablity and a will point to that new object while b is still pointing to old), so b==a will be false   
if(b == a) { 
System.out.println("Stranger"); 
}   
a--; //again a new Integer Object will be created and now a will start pointing to that new Object , so b==a will be false   
if(b == a) { 
System.out.println("Strangest");
}
```