# Configure SWIG to create an appropriate Java data type for C function with an int32_t output parameter

Tags: java, swig

I'm having issues passing in an appropriate Java data type for the fetchByType C function's length parameter from my Java implementation (both below).  On the C side, the *length parameter is a pointer to a length variable (output) to indicate the size of the data to be returned from the fetchByType C function.  I've tried to use the SWIG %apply int32_t { int32_t * } and pass an int initialized at 0 from my Java implementation but that fails.  I've also tried passing in a SWIGTYPE_p_int as shown below, but that also doesn't work. I don't have an exception unfortunately as this just crashes.

C Function:

```
void * fetchByType(struct row_t *result_row, type_t attribute, int32_t *length);
```

Generated Java from SWIG:

```
public static String fetchByType(SWIGTYPE_p_result_row_t result_row, type_t attribute, SWIGTYPE_p_int length)
```

Java Implementation:

```
SWIGTYPE_p_int length = new SWIGTYPE_p_int();
fetchByType(result_row, attribute, length)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to pass something that can be changed into the C function. That means you can't use a primitive in Java (e.g. `int`) since Java *always* passes primitives by value.

There's only really one sensible way you can work around this. SWIG in fact already provides a few typemap we can use that passes this as an array instead. Arrays in Java are "objects" and so `int[]` is passed by reference even though `int` isn't. A simplified example based on the function you show above, first test.h:

```
inline void fetchByType(int32_t *length) {
  *length = 123;
}
```

And a module file, test.i:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

// knows about things like int *OUTPUT:
%include "typemaps.i"
// knows about int32_t
%include "stdint.i"
// let's have an int32_t *OUTPUT for our int32_t *lenght
%apply int32_t *OUTPUT { int32_t *length }

%include "test.h"
```

This just makes sure we apply the appropriate `*OUTPUT` typemap. (stdint.i maps this onto a real C primitive for you). I tested with:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    int arr[] = new int[1];
    test.fetchByType(arr);
    System.out.println(arr[0]);
  }
}
```

It's a bit of a hack<sup>1</sup>, but it's usable. Another approach might be to use a [`java.lang.Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), which also represents an `int` and is a proper `Object` so gets passed by reference. The problem there is that `java.lange.Integer` [is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560176/java-is-integer-immutable) however and I'm not actually sure enough how that works on the JNI side to provide an example of this.

<sup>1</sup> Other languages SWIG supports alter the return type for some typemaps and return a tuple or similar for OUTPUT arguments, but that's not really feasible with Java.

Comment: I was able to use your example, great solution.  I tried to use an Integer but then on the Java side you can only pass an Integer as null or with a default value (Integer length = new Integer(0)) but neither way worked.  The Integer length=null actually threw a null pointer which makes sense.  Is it good practice to include any .i files right after the %module declaration?  I moved the typemaps.i and the stdint.i there and my generated code seems ok...any downside to that?

Comment: @c12 - I have a strong suspicion that the other approach I mentioned using `Integer` instead is actually not possible in Java at all, at least not without altering the return type which defeats the point. As for the `%include` - it doesn't matter much where you put them, so long as they're before the first place they're needed. The `%{ #include "test.h" %}` just tells SWIG to pass `#include "test.h"` straight to the generated wrapper, so it really doesn't make any difference which is first there. My habit is to stick anything that needs to be `#include`d at the top and then follow w/`%include`