# get method return value

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i run following codes in eclipse:

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> list = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// add some elements ti list
list.add(new StringBuilder("hello"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("2"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("hi"));
list.add(new StringBuilder("this"));

// add some elements to alist
alist.add(4);
alist.add(9);


//get method
StringBuilder a = list.get(3);
a.append(" is a good day");
int b = alist.get(1);
b = 7;

// print the list
System.out.println("LinkedList:" + list);
System.out.println("ArrayList:" + alist);
```

and result is here

```
LinkedList:[hello, 2, hi, this is a good day]
ArrayList:[4, 9]
```

It looks like get method returns a shallow copy of list element (in the case of StringBuilder) to the a, but returns a deep copy (in the case of integer) to the b!
why it happened? Do the get method return a deep or shallow copy of list's elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Integer Immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560176/is-integer-immutable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` returns a reference to the `List` element, not a copy (neither deep nor shallow).

In the first snippet you mutate the object referenced by variable `a`, so the `List` is also affected:

```
StringBuilder a = list.get(3);
a.append(" is a good day");
```

In the second snippet you assign a new value to the variable `b`, which doesn't affect the `List`:

```
int b = alist.get(1);
b = 7;
```

In order for your first snippet to behave as the second, you should write:

```
StringBuilder a = list.get(3);
a = new StringBuilder(" is a good day");
```

and the `List` won't be affected.

On the other way, you can't make the second snippet behave as the first. Even if you assigned the `List` element to an `Integer` variable, you can't call any method that would mutate it, since `Integer` is immutable.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `StringBuilder a = list.get(3);` you get a reference to element at index `3` assigned to variable `a` , modifying using `a` will affect element at index `3`. where as `int b = alist.get(1);` you get a copy of element at `1` assigned to variable `b` so modifying it will not affect element at `1`. there is not connection between `b` and element at `1` after assignment .

```
   StringBuilder a = list.get(3);
    a.append(" is a good day");
    int b = alist.get(1);
    b = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder a = list.get(3);
a.append(" is a good day");
int b = alist.get(1);
b = 7;
```

Indeed you create a shallow copy of your list element in `int b =...`. As your List contains Objects of Type Integer you make a new assignment to a primitive integer here, while with the StringBuilder you work on exactly the same object.