# If a = b, what happens if each value changes respectively?

Tags: java, variables

What happens if you change the variable `b`, or what if you change `a`. What does the order have to do with anything.

I know `count = count + 1` but the two variables is messing up my brain.

```
b = 7;
a = 7;
a = b;
a += 1;
```

What happens to `b`?

Comment: Please post a complete, reproducible snippet of code and add the Java tag. You can do so using the "edit" link.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help

Comment: Nothing happens to b.  Read up on Lvalues vs Rvalues.

Comment: Try to run your code... System.out.println.....

Comment: Do you know about raw types? Instances, references? Short answer: If b would change, it would mess up not only your head but everyone's. It'd make life a lot harder.

Comment: Ok but why does this have to be down voted. This community is really hostile. I was in an environment where I couldn't run my code (school library)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What happens to `b`?

Nothing happens to `b`.

When you do

```
a = b;
```

you're copying **the value** stored in `b` and putting it in `a`. (You're *not* making `a` an alias of `b`.)

When you then do `a += 1;` you're changing the value stored in `a` (and the value stored in `b` remains unchanged).

You can verify this by printing the final values after your code snippet:

```
System.out.println(a);  // prints 8
System.out.println(b);  // prints 7
```

> What happens if you change the variable `b`, or what if you change `a`. What does the order have to do with anything.

`a` and `b` are two independent variables and changing one will never affect the other.

The order matters since when you do `a = b` the value of `b` is copied into `a` and whatever `a` stored before is discarded. If you had done `a += 1` prior to `a = b`, then `a` would have been restored to 7 again.

Comment: Yeah I did. Also, why does this have downvotes? I wasn't able to print or do anything because I was at the library and couldn't run code.

Comment: That's not a very common situation to be in so I think people just downvoted for "lack of effort". A future tip, you can use http://ideone.com (example: http://ideone.com/xaoGwm).

Answer (score 2):

**int** is raw type you don't copy reference but the value itself. This will work same way for **Integer** because it is **immutable** class.

```
 int b = 7;
 int a = 7;
 a = b;
 a+=1;
 System.out.println(a);// ->8
 System.out.println(b);// ->7
```

Comment: Your reference to `Integer` is a bit confusing. There's more to it than just immutability. (You wouldn't be able to do `+=` if it wasn't for autoboxing for instance.)

Comment: @aioobe for sure more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3085357/4327527) I just want to avoid confusing why some classes does not works as reference.

Answer (score 1):

Still 7.
integer is raw type and if you assign a int variable to another int, just its value is received by the new one. Not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

b stays 7.
a becomes 8.

You could use `System.out.println();` to print values of variables and find out yourself if you ever doubt.
That or use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int b = 7; // b points to 7
        int a = 7; // a points to 7
        a = b; // b and a points to 7
        a += 1; // a points to 8 now, b is still pointing to 7
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
```

**output**

```
8
7
```

When we do `a += 1;` we change the value stored in `a` (value stored in `b` is still same).